# python List from function

Tags: python, list, parameters, function

i got a Problem, i am creating 2 lists in a function, but i cannot work with them outside the function because it says "NameError: name "ListB" is not defined".

I need the list to create a tuple and write the tuple into a dictonary :)

```
#
#create 2 lists and 1 dictonary with the same length
#Example: index length is 3
def adder():

    ListB = list()
    ListC = list()

    while True:

        insert1 = input("List2 add: ")
        insert2 = input("List3 add: ")

        ListB.append(insert1)
        ListC.append(insert2)

        print("""if list length is ok, write "ok" """)
        inputPerson = str(input())

        if inputPerson == "ok":
            break

    return ListB, ListC

#run adder
adder = adder()

list2 = [] # create list2/3 with same index length 
list3 = [] # to add ListB to list2 and ListC to list3

list2.append(ListB) #add ListB to list2
list3.append(ListC) #add ListC to list3


tupleList = list(zip(list2, list3)) # take element from list2 and
print(tupleList)  #Test             # list3 in (x, y) order

#create a dictonary with they keyword KeyX X = 0,1,2,3...n : tupleList[0]..[n]
#depending on index length, but X = tupleList[n]!!
dict_List = { \
    'Key0' : tupleList[0],
    'Key1' : tupleList[1],
    'Key2' : tupleList[2],
    }

#print out the result
print("Dict_List:", dict_List)
print("Key0", dict_List['Key0'])
print("Key1", dict_List['Key1'])
print("Key2", dict_List['Key2'])
```

Right now i dont know how to create a dictonary that will automatically 
create a new "entry" with KeyX etc.

I hope somebody will help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
ListB, ListC = adder()
```

As your function returns two values, you can unpack them like a tuple.

What you have to know is that declaring a variable from within a function make it local and limited to the function's scope. So, you can not access it from outside.

When you call `adder()`, the returned value does not have any name, it is just a value and you have to assign it to a new variable like you did: `adder = adder()`. This means that the variable `adder` now contains the two returned lists.

However, you are overwritting your function (as the names are the same) and this is considered as bad practice. You better should do something like `lists = adder()`.

Then, you can access the created `ListB` with `lists[0]`. But as I said, you can also directly unpack it: `ListB, ListC = adder()`.

Comment: I thank you very much, i didnt know what adder = adder() is a bad style. Many programmers are using this in videos.

Comment: Maybe you know how to create a dynamic dictonary?

Comment: @MartinM If I understand what you are trying to do, you might use dict comprehension: `dict_List = {i: tuples[i] for i in range(len(tuples))}` with `tuples = list(zip(ListB, ListC))`. I am not sure you need `list2` and `list3`.